# Get code of webpage via js ( inspected code not Source code)

Tags: javascript, function

I have a web page https://wpt1.ide4.bid/

The source code and Inspected code via chrome are different.

Is there any way to get inspected code via js after page load or 5 seconds and store it?

How would i achieve this?

currently i am not able to get the javascript working because it saves source code.

```
document.getElementById("main-region").textContent.indexOf('Thank You For scheduling 22')
```

Any help will be aprreciated!

Comment: JavaScript running where? Store it where?

Comment: @Quentin Store it in a variable and i am running in web browser currently, later i will implement it in header via script if it works, i have updated my question. Please check

Comment: Are you looking to get the html render in iframe from calendly? Because that is the only part which is dynamically loading after page load.

Comment: @PraveenPoonia Yes Exactly Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below solution to get the html of iframe once page is loaded -

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    // Code to execute when all DOM content is loaded. 
        var iframeInnerHtml = document.querySelector('.calendly-inline-widget > iframe').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
        console.log(iframeInnerHtml);
});
```

Comment: it returns Undefined, can you please add to check text "Thank You For scheduling 22"  inside DIV with ID "main-region". Thanks

Comment: Try this -  `var iframeContainer = document.querySelector('.calendly-inline-widget');
console.log(iframeContainer);
var iframe = iframeContainer.querySelector('iframe');
console.log(iframe);
var iframeInnerHtml = iframe.contentWindow.window.document.body.innerHTML;
console.log(iframeInnerHtml);`

Comment: Can you please help me to check the content inside it "15 Minutes".

Comment: @NimeshDeo - what content you want to check? Share the code or dom object.

Comment: Inside iframe there is a div with id "main-region" inside that div I need to look for text "Thanks For scheduling" each 5 seconds. Please help me achieve it.
Thanks